# Разобрать текс на слова, переносы строк

Tags: javascript

```
.split("")
```

Так получаем на выходе массив из символов, который включает слова, пробелы и переносы строк

```
.split(" ")
```

Получаем массив в котором только слова, местами просто пустые значения, без пробелов. Переносы строк получаются так

```
\nLorem
```

Вопрос в том, как разобрать текст так, чтобы массив содержал отдельно пробелы, отдельно переносы строк и отдельно слова?

```js
 console.log(text.textContent.match(/[a-zа-яё0-9]+|\s+|[^\w\s]+/gi));
```

```css
  #test, #text {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    max-width: 30%
  }
```

```html
<div id=text>

  Lorem   
  ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  Praesentium nemo dolores debitis, maxime quia ipsum quasi
officiis id libero tenetur autem similique iure itaque optio quis beatae minima! Libero, eaque!
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: .split("")
в данном случае сплита не происходит

Comment: Как мне получить желаемый результат?

Comment: Можно перебирать текст посимвольно. Но, думаю, проще будет разбить текст на строки и посчитать количество строк. Затем разбиваем строки на слова, записываем их в массив. Добавляем в массив нужное количество пробелов и переносов строк.

Comment: Возможно решить данную задачу при помощи регулярного выражения?

Comment: @Лена Каким именно образом вы собираетесь использовать регулярное выражение? Если речь о том, чтобы просто подставить регулярку в качестве аргумента split и на выходе получить массив, содержащий отдельно пробелы, отдельно переносы строк и отдельно слова - нет, чудес не бывает..

Answer (score 5):

Типичная [XY Problem](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy)... Вы пытаетесь **разделить** строку, а необходимо **найти** в строке!

Поэтому правильнее будет использование метода `match()`, вместо `split()`.

Также не забывайте, что знаки препинания тоже должны быть отдельными элементами, так как не относятся ни к словам, ни к пробельным символам.

```js
const sTXT = `Вопрос в том, как разобрать текст так, чтобы массив содержал: отдельно пробелы, отдельно переносы строк и отдельно слова???  
Как мне получить желаемый результат?`;

const rEXP = /[a-zа-яё0-9]+|\s|[^\w\s]+/gi;

console.log( sTXT.match(rEXP) );
```

Comment: Здорово, почти работает. Вот только если идут к примеру 2 или 3 и более перенос строк подряд, то регулярка такие переносы не разделяет.  И пробелы до и после переноса, они тоже вместе с переносом. А так неплохо, но хотелось бы решить этот недочет. Подкрепила скриншет

Comment: @Лена, в таких случаях нужно привести пример строки (и не картинкой). Де есть "такая" строка и нужно из нее получить вот "это"... Так будет более понятнее.

Comment: Добавила пример кода

Comment: @Лена, уже лучше. Теперь осталось понять что не устраивает в таком решении...

Comment: Если несколько переносов подряд, получается, что он их все вместе берет. Тогда как необходимо каждый перенос отдельно. Некоторые символы переносов выхватывает вместе с пробелами, а необходимо, чтобы перенос и пробелы были по отдельности.

Comment: @Лена, Вы серьёзно? Я оставил простор для творчества, а оказывается, что Вам нужно полностью готовое. Ну, что ж... подправил...

Comment: со split - было бы проще

Comment: @Grundy, вполне возможно. Только есть подозрение, что появись какие-либо новые условия, всё равно пришлось бы на match переделывать.